# Scala reflection error: this is an inner module, use reflectModule on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ModuleMirror

Tags: scala, macros, scala-2.10

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11053571/53013), I'm trying to figure out how to call a method on an object. The relevant definitions are:

```
trait ThirdParty { def invoke = println("right") }
trait WeatherIcon { def invoke = println("wrong") }
class MyClass {
    object objA extends ThirdParty
    object objB extends WeatherIcon
}
```

I got a `Symbol` for `objA` like this:

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

val stuff = typeOf[MyClass].members.filter(_.isValue).filter(_.typeSignature <:< typeOf[ThirdParty])
```

That returns an `Iterable` with a single element, so let's say:

```
val objASymbol = stuff.head.asModuleSymbol
```

I then tried, based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11020746/53013), this:

```
val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
mirror.reflectModule(objASymbol)
```

Which resulted in the error message quoted on the subject:

```
java.lang.Error: this is an inner module, use reflectModule on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ModuleMirror
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.reflectModule(JavaMirrors.scala:118)
    at scala.reflect.runtime.JavaMirrors$JavaMirror.reflectModule(JavaMirrors.scala:60)
```

The problem is that I can't figure out what this error message is telling me to do!

Comment: In your example, what is `res6`?

Comment: @Nicolas Sorry, I copied from the wrong place. It's just `objASymbol` I declared right before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to write `runtimeMirror.reflect(<instance of MyClass>).reflectModule(objASymbol)`. Plain reflectModule won't do, because some reflective operations on `objA` (e.g. getting its instance) require an outer instance.

Unfortunately, your use case won't work even if you write it right, because M4 only supports static objects: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5498. We'll implement this before 2.10.0-final.