# Reflection: Getting module mirror from inner class mixed into a singleton object

Tags: scala, reflection, inner-classes

I am having trouble finding the `apply` method of a case class' companion object when that case class is defined as inner class, in the following scenario:

```
case class Outer()

trait Foo {
  case class Inner()
}

object Bar extends Foo
```

Approach so far:

```
import reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => cm, universe => ru}

def getApplyMethod[A: ru.TypeTag]: ru.MethodSymbol = {
  val sym     = ru.typeOf[A].typeSymbol
  val clazz   = sym.asClass
  val mod     = clazz.companionSymbol.asModule
  if (!mod.isStatic) println(s"Oh oh... $mod")  // and now?
  val im      = cm.reflect(cm.reflectModule(mod).instance)
  val ts      = im.symbol.typeSignature
  val mApply  = ts.member(ru.newTermName("apply")).asMethod
  mApply
}

getApplyMethod[Outer]
getApplyMethod[Bar.Inner]  // oh oh, detected, but what do to?
```

The suggestion from the compiler is:

```
object Inner is an inner module,
  use reflectModule on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ModuleMirror
```

So how would I go about this, given that the only information `getApplyMethod` has is the `TypeTag[Bar.Inner]`?

---

**Note** that this problem is introduced by mixing in `Inner` from a trait. If I had

```
object Bar { case class Inner() }
```

it works fine, the `Inner` module is "static".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the companion object instance of a inner modul with the Scala reflection API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440124/get-the-companion-object-instance-of-a-inner-modul-with-the-scala-reflection-api)

Comment: @senia I saw that question. But (a) there you have an actual value to take an instance mirror from, (b) it doesn't cover the general case where both static and non-static can occur.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is, if a type is path-dependent, does the TypeTag encode the path?

Because working from the instance is easy:

```
scala> trait Foo { case class Inner(i: Int) }
defined trait Foo

scala> object Bar extends Foo
defined object Bar

scala> import reflect.runtime._
import reflect.runtime._

scala> import universe._
import universe._

scala> currentMirror reflect Bar.Inner
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for Inner

scala> res0.symbol.typeSignature.member(newTermName("apply")).asMethod
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodSymbol = method apply

scala> res0 reflectMethod res1
res3: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = method mirror for Foo.Inner.apply(i: scala.Int): Foo.this.Inner (bound to Inner)

scala> res3(7)
res4: Any = Inner(7)
```

Getting the enclosing object by hand from the type:

```
scala> typeOf[Bar.Inner]
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Bar.Inner

scala> val TypeRef(pre, sym, args) = res0
pre: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = Bar.type
sym: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class Inner
args: List[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List()

scala> pre.typeSymbol.asClass.companionSymbol.asModule
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleSymbol = object Bar

scala> currentMirror reflectModule res1
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleMirror = module mirror for Bar (bound to null)

scala> res2.instance
res3: Any = Bar$@22a71ac

scala> currentMirror reflect res3
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for Bar$@22a71ac

scala> res4.symbol
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.ClassSymbol = object Bar
```

Then drill back down to `Inner`:

```
scala> res5.typeSignature.member(newTermName("Inner"))
res7: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = object Inner

scala> res7.asModule
res9: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleSymbol = object Inner

scala> res9.moduleClass
res10: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = object Inner

scala> res10.typeSignature
res11: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = 
scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1[scala.Int,Foo.this.Inner]
        with scala.Serializable {
  def <init>(): Foo.this.Inner.type
  final override def toString(): java.lang.String
  case def apply(i: scala.Int): Foo.this.Inner
  case def unapply(x$0: Foo.this.Inner): scala.Option[scala.Int]
  private def readResolve(): java.lang.Object
}

scala> res11.member(newTermName("apply"))
res12: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method apply
```

Or using the `sym`:

```
scala> res5.typeSignature.member(sym.name)
res16: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = class Inner

scala> res16.asClass.companionSymbol
res17: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = object Inner

scala> res17.typeSignature.member(newTermName("apply"))
res18: reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol = method apply
```

Using it:

```
scala> res4 reflectModule res9
res20: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleMirror = module mirror for Foo.Inner (bound to Bar$@22a71ac)

scala> res20.instance
res22: Any = Inner

scala> currentMirror reflect res22
res23: reflect.runtime.universe.InstanceMirror = instance mirror for Inner

scala> res23 reflectMethod res18.asMethod
res24: reflect.runtime.universe.MethodMirror = method mirror for Foo.Inner.apply(i: scala.Int): Foo.this.Inner (bound to Inner)

scala> res24(7)
res25: Any = Inner(7)
```

Comment: Thanks. Where did the `TermName` constructor come from? For me (Scala 2.10.2), only `newTermName` (in `universe`) works.

Comment: @0__ yes it's renamed in 2.11.