# Find the outer class when provided an instance of the inner class

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-2.11

Is there a way to get the parent class from an instance of an inner class using macros rather than [run-time reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522042/135978)?

I have a set of classes like this:

```
trait IdProvider {
  type IdObject = Id.type
  case class Id(underlying: Int)
}

case class SomeEntity(id: SomeEntity.Id)

object SomeEntity extends IdProvider
```

And some code that works with arbitrary `IdProvider#Id`s:

```
val lookup = Map[IdProvider#IdObject, Set[Operation]]

def can(operation: Operation, id: IdProvider#Id): Boolean = {
    val idObject = findIdTypeFromInstance(id)  // This is what I don't have
    lookup.get(idObject).exists(s => s(operation))
}
```

Taking a leaf out of [this gist by Paul P.](https://gist.github.com/paulp/4692921) I now have this macro:

```
def findIdTypeFromInstance[T <: AnyRef : c.WeakTypeTag](
    c: blackbox.Context)(thing: c.Expr[T]): c.Expr[T] = {
  import c.universe._
  val companion = thing.actualType.typeSymbol.companion match {
    case NoSymbol =>
      c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"Instance of ${thing.actualType} has no companion object")
    case sym => sym
  }

  def make[U: c.WeakTypeTag] = c.Expr[U](internal.gen.mkAttributedRef(companion))

  make(c.WeakTypeTag(companion.typeSignature))
}
```

This works for simpler cases (top level case classes, classes and objects, and even nested case classes).  However, when dealing with the `IdProvider` setup above the macro tries to generate this tree:

```
Select(This(TypeName("IdProvider")), TermName("Id"))
```

This results in an extremely long stack trace in my test, which starts with:

> scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: value  is not a member of my.spec.MacroSpec

I have not been able to find a path from the instance or the companion (`IdProvider#Id`) to the parent class (in this case `SomeEntity`).  Is there a way to get to `SomeEntity` or do I have to use [run-time reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16522042/135978)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Id` companion is basically a lazy val. You need the enclosing instance to retrieve its value because it's not a statically defined stable path.

With `-Yshow-syms` you can see it get added in `mixin` phase:

```
      object SomeEntity
          constructor SomeEntity
*         method Id$lzycompute (private)
          method apply (case <synthetic>)
              value id
          method readResolve (private <synthetic>)
          method unapply (case <synthetic>)
              value x$0 (<synthetic>)
*         object Id (<synthetic> <stable>)
          value <local SomeEntity>
*         variable Id$module (private <local> <synthetic>)
```

The `$outer` field of an `Id` is added in `explicitouter`.

Is it easier just to expose the companion reference explicitly?

```
  case class Id(underlying: Int) {
    def c = Id
  }
```

This is just a quick look; maybe there's a clever way to do it.

Comment: That's a good idea - I'm already exposing the outer instance (via a `self` type) so I may be able to get in that way.