# Instantiating all classes that extend trait in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, reflection

So I'm building a library, and the problem I have is as follows:

I have a trait, such as

```
package my.library
trait Animal {
  def randomFunctions
}
```

What I need to know is all the classes the consumer code has, that extend/implement said trait, such as

```
package code.consumer
case class Cat extends Animal
case class Dog extends Animal
```

So in summary: inside my library (which has the trait) I need to find out all classes (in consumer code) that extend/implement the trait.

Comment: So the trait will be in a library and the subclasses in a different library ?

Comment: The trait will be in a library, and the subclasses will be in the consumer code (?)

Comment: As long as you import the library in the consumer code there should not be an issue. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: The problem is that I need to find out all the extending classes, that are in consumer code, inside the library

Comment: oh ok  i see. Please update the question to reflect this.

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530694/get-all-the-classes-that-implments-a-trait-in-scala-using-reflection

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya that is close, but I would like to avoid using external libraries, and instead use the reflection API

Comment: I see another one here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053571/how-to-use-scala-reflection-api-to-get-all-contained-classes  Have you tried searching existing questions?

Comment: I did search, but either the questions didn't answer my question directly enough, or seemed too complex for my need

Comment: ok let me put together something when i find the time.

Comment: Is the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490779/scala-reflection-loading-or-finding-classes-based-on-trait relevant?

Comment: @Touko might be, need to delve deeper into it

Comment: Didn't unfortunately solve my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally solved this by using reflections (https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) with the following little snippet:

```
val reflection = new Reflections()
reflection.getSubTypesOf(classOf[Animal])
```

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use a `sealed trait`. This forces all implementations of the trait to reside in the same file as the trait was defined.

This would break your separation of consumer and library code but you would be sure to get all implementations.

The only other option I can think of is to use an IDE, like IntelliJ which has an option to find all implementation based on given trait.

Comment: Unfortunately the separation of consumer and library code is quite necessary in this case