# Scala : Error when using reflection to load class and methods

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I have a class

```
class LrGen extends IModelGen {

  var header = Array(
    "First name",
    "last name",
    "address",
    "city",
    "state",
    "zip"
  )

  override def getHeader(separator:String): String =
  {
    header.mkString(separator)
  }

}
```

I am trying to invoke the getHeader method of that class using reflection following: [How to invoke method on companion object via reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134803/how-to-invoke-method-on-companion-object-via-reflection) but modified slightly as my class name will vary as well. My code looks like:

```
val clazzToInvoke = classInitialName+ "Gen"+"$"
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

// get runtime universe
val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe

// get runtime mirror
val rm = ru.runtimeMirror(this.getClass.getClassLoader)

// get instance mirror for companion object for the class
val moduleSymbol  = rm.reflect(Class.forName(clazzToInvoke))


val methodGetHeader = ru.typeOf[clazzToInvoke.type].decl(ru.TermName("getHeader")).asMethod

println(methodGetHeader("\t"))
```

However, I am getting error:

```
error: ru.MethodSymbol does not take parameters
[ERROR]     println(methodGetHeader("\t")
```

Any insight? Thanks in advance.

For reference My interface looks like :

```
trait  IModelGen
{
  def getHeader(separator:String): String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you are missing:

```
val methodHi = instanceMirror.reflectMethod(methodGetHeader)
methodGetHeader()
```

and for your reference link: it's used for invoking the **object/singleton** method, but for `LrGen` is a class not a **singleton object**.

so maybe you need to **instantiate** a class and **invoke** `getHeader` method, like:

```
val lr = classOf[LrGen].getConstructors()(0).newInstance().asInstanceOf[LrGen]
lr.getHeaders("\t")
```