# Why is scala reflection reporting no declarations for certain classes?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

According to the [docs here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.reflect.api.Types%24TypeApi), `declarations` should be a subset of `members` for the things declared in the class, not inherited.  Then why do various classes report no declarations?

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
scala> typeTag[java.lang.System].tpe.declarations
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = SynchronizedOps()
```

Comment: The class `java.lang.System` does not have any members in Scala. The static members are on the companion object. This post tells you how to get it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api

Comment: That code throws an exception if I try it with `java.lang.System`, because it looks for `System$`. It's not obvious how to get a list of static methods that way.

Comment: scala> typeOf[System].typeSymbol.companionSymbol.typeSignature.declarations
res5: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = SynchronizedOps(value in, value out, value err, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that both `members` and `declarations` only take into account object members. However, all functions declared in `java.lang.System` are static.

This makes sense because from the scala point of view there are no static members. The equivalent of a static member is a method/value defined in a module (using `object` instead of `class`). So scala-reflection will act as if static members of a Java-class are defined in a module --- more specifically in the companion object of the java-class. (Note that in contrast to scala defined companion objects these "java-companion-objects" do not exist on a VM level).

I'm no expert in scala reflection, so I can't tell you how you would find the static members :-(

Comment: To find the static members, see Eugene's comment under my question.