# Scala Object - get reference from string (in Scala 2.10)

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I would like to be able to get an instance of a Scala Object from a String specified in config. Say for example I have a config property `db.driver = "scala.slick.driver.H2Driver"`

I would like to be able to get an instance of this object `H2Driver`. Obviously I could create a map of configs to actual objects, but that seems like a hassle. I could also do this by including a $ on the end of the config and loading up the module, i.e.

```
   val cl = Class.forName("scala.slick.driver.H2Driver$") //note the $
   val driverObj = cl.getField("MODULE$").get(null).asInstanceOf[JdbcProfile]
```

But I was hoping there was a neater way to do this in Scala 2.10 using the newer reflections API.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer. I realised you are looking for a solution in 2.10 not 2.11

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same in 2.10:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import reflect.runtime._
import reflect.runtime._

scala> currentMirror staticModule "scala.Array"
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleSymbol = object Array

scala> currentMirror reflectModule res0
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.ModuleMirror = module mirror for scala.Array (bound to null)

scala> .instance
res2: Any = scala.Array$@67b467e9
```