# Cannot get companion object given a class name

Tags: scala, reflection

Based on another post I am trying to get a companion object for a class given the class name. But I cannot get it to compile:

```
val clazz = Class.forName(className)
val rootMirror = scala.reflect.runtime.universe.runtimeMirror(clazz.getClassLoader)
val classSymbol = rootMirror.classSymbol(clazz)
val classMirror = rootMirror.reflectClass(classSymbol)
val moduleMirror = classMirror.companion.get
```

But the last line gives me the following compiler error:

```
- value companion is not a member of reflect.runtime.universe.ClassMirror
```

I am using scala version 2.10.4. Orginal post: [Get companion object instance with new Scala reflection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020746/get-companion-object-instance-with-new-scala-reflection-api)

Comment: Maybe a bug. Can you move forward to 2.11.x?

Comment: No as I have dependencies that only work in 2.10.x