# How can I get companion object from a class name?

Tags: scala

I have some spark model files and I want to load them. One way is to write the following codes.

```
LogisticRegressionModel.load(path)
```

However, I need to have a model object so that I call `LogisticRegressionModel.load`. I only get class name like `org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel`, so I need to reflect companion object from class name, but how can I do this?

[From this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026090/cannot-get-companion-object-given-a-class-name), I find there is a maybe broken way. But when I tried, I find no `companion` field in `classMirror`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know a type in compile time, you can try using slightly newer API that works in 2020:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def findCompanionOf[T: TypeTag] =
  runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    .reflectModule(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.companionSymbol.asModule)
    .instance
```

```
@ findCompanionOf[Long]
res15: Any = object scala.Long
```

If you know only name as a `String` or as `Class[_]`... then if companion exists it's `.class` name + `$`, while the instance should be available in static field `MODULE$`.

```
def findCompanionOf(clazz: Class[_]) =
  clazz.getClassLoader
    .loadClass(classOf[List[_]].getName + "$")
    .getField("MODULE$")
    .get(null) // obtaining static field = obtaining value for null instance
```

```
@ findCompanionOf(classOf[List[_]])
res25: Class[?0] = class scala.collection.immutable.List$
```

In both cases if class/type doesn't have an companion then code with throw, though the second version also won't work with primitives like `Long`, `Int`, etc.

In your case something like:

```
findCompanionOf(
  getClass.getClassLoader.loadClass("org.apache.spark.ml.classification.LogisticRegressionModel")
)
```

might work.