# List of inner classes/objects during compilation

Tags: scala

This is the simplified code of a class(object) I'm working on:

```
object T {
  val default = A
  val options = List(A,B,C)

  sealed trait T
  object A extends T {
    override def toString = "A"
  }
  object B extends T {
    override def toString = "B"
  }
  object C extends T {
    override def toString = "C"
  }
}
```

This hierarchy maps directly to GUI element which requires a `options = List(A,B,C)` to build.

**Problem with current approach:**

- Every time I add an extra object I have to change the `option` manually. This isn't too much work however the code isn't too elegant this way.

**My question is:**

*Can I generate a list of inner objects during compile time? I wouldn't like to do this during runtime, it would be an overkill.*

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot as this is equivalent to having a list of fields or methods that a class contains, sort of. There might be some trick via `scala.reflection` API that I am not aware of, though, but it is highly unlikely.

Comment: You can do this easily using Scala macros.

Comment: There is a solution via scala.reflection here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893712/detect-inner-objects-in-a-scala-object

Comment: @Samar, this is correct, however deprecated. `members` instead of `declarations` will work though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to @Samar's comment, to make it clear. The following is what you need:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

case object K {
  val default = A
  val options = getObjects[this.type]

  sealed trait T

  object A extends T {
    override def toString = "A"
  }

  object B extends T {
    override def toString = "B"
  }

  object C extends T {
    override def toString = "C"
  }

  def getObjects[T: TypeTag] = typeOf[T].members.collect {
    case m: ModuleSymbol if m.isModule => m
  }.toList
}
```